# FreeBSD gcc install

Tags: gcc, freebsd

Здравствуйте.
Стараюсь поставить на FreeBSD 7 x64 gcc посвежее родного 4.2.1.
Из портов не ставится. Жалуется на отсутсвие GMP и MPFR (или их кривой путь).
По [этому](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9450394/how-to-install-gcc-from-scratch-with-gmp-mpfr-mpc-elf-without-shared-librari) ответу поставил нужные библиотеки и с их помощью конфигурил make, который потомвыдавал:

```
Error expanding embedded variable.
Error code 2
```

Пробовал так же по вышеуказанному ответу собирать gmake'ом, но процесс съедает всю оперативку, и завершается:

```
virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory
gmake[2]: *** [insn-recog.o] Error 1
gmake[2]: Leaving directory `/root/tmp/gcc-4.9.1/host-x86_64-unknown-freebsd7.2/gcc'
gmake[1]: *** [all-gcc] Error 2
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/root/tmp/gcc-4.9.1'
gmake: *** [all] Error 2
```

Прошу помочь разобраться с этим вопросом.

Comment: Если процесс компиляции выедает всю оперативную память, почему бы не начать с того, что увеличить объём раздела подкачки. Или создать, если его не было.

Comment: Ниже вашей ссылки есть более простой ответ: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10662297/934691

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Как насчет дополнительного свапа?
Создайте файл нужного размера при помощи dd

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/usr/swap0 bs=1m count=64
```

Затем его нужно разметить как swap

```
mkswap /usr/swap0
```

И задействовать

```
swapon /usr/swap0
```